# How to write Xpath for next Div using Sibling

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

I want to read the Tax Price using the sibling concept, so I have I've written below XPath, but it's not working

My code:

```
//div[@class='grid_3 d-grid_10']//label[contains(text(), 'Tax')]/following-sibling::div
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid_3 d-grid_10"> 
    <label class="m-confirmation-modal-print-detail-capgrey"> Tax:</label>
</div> 
<div class="grid_1 d-grid_2"> 
    <label class="m-confirmation-modal-print-price text-align-right"> $10.50</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: What is the element you are trying to locate? post the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read the *Tax Price* i.e. **$10.50** using text **Tax** within the ancestor node, you need to locate the `<label>` node with text as **Tax:** first. Then with respect to this node you need to locate the following `<div>` node which have a decedent node containing the required text i.e. **$10.50** and to achieve that you can use the following solution:

- `XPath`:

  ```
  //label[@class='m-confirmation-modal-print-detail-capgrey' and contains(.,'Tax')]//following::div[1]/label
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The second `<div>` is a sibling of the first one, not of the child `<label>`. You need to go back to the parent `<div>` first using `..` or `parent::div`

```
//div[@class='grid_3 d-grid_10']//label[contains(text(), 'Tax')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div
```

As suggested in the comments you can simplify it by starting the `xpath` with the "Tax" `<label>`

```
//label[contains(text(), 'Tax')]/parent::div[@class='grid_3 d-grid_10']/following-sibling::div
```

Comment: This kind of *"recursion"* : `parent->child->parent` can be simplified: `//label[contains(text(), 'Tax')]/parent::div[@class='grid_3 d-grid_10']/following-sibling::div` - no need to specify the same parent `div` twice

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
//label[contains(text(), 'Tax')]/../following-sibling::div
```